# My simple react component does not render on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, jsfiddle

This is the first time to use jsfiddle as i always use jsbin, my problem is that my simple **Hello** component does not render correctly and i get an error 'Unclosed regular expression', it seems there is a problem in jsx rendering despite i am working on jsx tranformer mode, so what is the problem here??

```
const Hello = () => {
  return (<h1>hello</h1>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Saherelgendy/0k8cued2/3/

Comment: Looks like you didn't include React. Your code is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/tg95nL2y/

Comment: @imjared yes fixed and works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your language from "javascript + react" to "React + React" in the drop down. Works for me after that.

Comment: Thank you it really works, weird because react is not a language

Comment: It's something to do with how it's handling JSX, wasn't picking it up properly when "Javascript" was selected as the language.

Comment: This makes more sense @Aaron Cohen